# How to get files and directories name using Gradle?

Tags: file, directory, gradle, task, filetree

I have **dir** in which another task create files and directories so in this dir there are files, directories, subdirectroies, files in them and ect. I want to put all absolute path of **files** and **directories** in a list.

```
def listNames = project.fileTree('dir')
```

But only the files are included in the list, directories are missing. How to collect all of them?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
def names = []
fileTree("baseDir").visit { FileVisitDetails details -> 
    names << details.file.path 
}
```

For further details, see `FileTree` in the [Gradle Javadoc](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/).

Comment: How do I get access to the FileVisitDetails type? I tried an import but no dice.

Answer (score 28):

The shorter version:

```
def files =  fileTree("dirName").filter { it.isFile() }.files.name
```

Of course it does the same thing.

Comment: Actually, your version just collects out files, while Peter's version collects directories and files. So they aren't the same.